# Grant to ad user the permission to write his email and telephonenumber fields only

Tags: active-directory

I read about the SELF group, can I use it to grant write permissions on their own single attributes(like email and phone number) to active directory users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Delegation of Control to delegate control of property specific permissions. Additionally, you can scope the Delegation of Control to just certain objects (users).